# MarkerClusterer xml markers

Tags: javascript, php, xml, google-maps, markerclusterer

What I am trying to do is to add a markerclusterer to my actual code for a map integrated in a webpage. All the markers are created via an xml file generated somewhere else.
The map is working fine and all is loaded well without markerclusterer.

I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. Maybe I didn't get how markerclusterer works correctly. I hope you can help me.

What I added to my initial (working) code are 3 lines:

- var markersclust = [];
- markersclust.push(point);
- var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersclust);

All is inside "script tags" but in a php file.

```
echo'
function load() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.8333,14.25),
zoom: 5,
mapTypeId: \'roadmap\'
});
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;  

downloadUrl("xml_map_public.php", function(data) {
var xml = data.responseXML;
var markersclust = [];
var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
var uid = markers[i].getAttribute("uid");
var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
markersclust.push(point);
var html = "<a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/"+ uid +"\" target=\"_new\"><b>" + name + "</b></a> <br/>" + address;
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: point
});
bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
}
});
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markersclust);
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, \'click\', function() {
infoWindow.setContent(html);
infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
new ActiveXObject(\'Microsoft.XMLHTTP\') :
new XMLHttpRequest;

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (request.readyState == 4) {
request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
callback(request, request.status);
}
};

request.open(\'GET\', url, true);
request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

';
```

Comment: Just to be sure...did you add this:

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>

Comment: yes I added the markerclusterer.js in a previous script...I tried even yours, but nothing changes! thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want this in your case:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: point
});

markersclust.push(marker);
```

Here is an example that I use as a base.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var mapOpts = {mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOpts);
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markerArray = [];

function makeMarker(options)
{var pushPin = new google.maps.Marker({map:map});
pushPin.setOptions(options);
google.maps.event.addListener(pushPin, "click", function(){infoWindow.setOptions(options);infoWindow.open(map, pushPin);});
markerBounds.extend(options.position);
markerArray.push(pushPin);
return pushPin;}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(){infoWindow.close();});

makeMarker({title: "Berlin, Germany",position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5234051, 13.4113999),content:""});
makeMarker({title: "220 E 42nd St, New York, NY 10017, USA",position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7501762, -73.9731466),content:""});
makeMarker({title: "San Francisco, CA, USA",position: new google.maps.LatLng(37.7749295, -122.4194155),content:""});
makeMarker({title: "Middletown, OH, USA",position: new google.maps.LatLng(39.5150576, -84.3982763),content:""});
makeMarker({title: "Twin Lakes, Salisbury, CT 06068, USA",position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.0264482, -73.3870791),content:""});
makeMarker({title: "Dearborn, MI, USA",position: new google.maps.LatLng(42.3222599, -83.1763145),content:""});
makeMarker({title: "Essen, Germany",position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.4556432, 7.0115552),content:""});

map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markerArray);

</script>
```

Comment: thanks for answering but this doesn't solve my issue

Comment: not already solved - I'm coding other parts of my web app. When I figure it out I will post the solution.